# how to replace a space with the name of a file, to build a route?

Tags: bash, shell, powershell, unix, cmd

I'm trying to make a copy of all the existing files in a folder to another folder. but I have problems with the names that have that blank

```
folder
-- new file.txt---->the problem 
-- file2.txt
-- file3.csv
```

i apply this mybatch.bat

```
 set FECHA=%date%
 set FECHA=%FECHA:/=%
 set FILE=D:\BACKUPS
 for %%i in (*) do (
     copy %cd%\%%i %FILE%\${%%~ni// /_}_%DATE%%%~xi
)
```

try to replace the blanks with "_" the following code, in a route

```
${%%~ni// /_}
```

but this does not run, it just comes out as string

```
D:\BACKUPS\${%%~ni// /_}_090519.txt
```

i want this

```
D:\BACKUPS\new_file_090519.txt
```

Comment: What a wild mix of tags and syntax used in the script. That isn't batch nor bash nor powershell. If you want a batch remove the not relevant tags. `cp %cd%\%%i %FILE%\${%%~ni// /_}_%DATE%%%~xi` => `copy "%%~fi" "%File%\%%~ni_%FECHA%%%~xi"`

Comment: yes @lit, do you have the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the PowerShell tag, here is a solution. When you are satisfied that the copy will be done correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Copy-Item` cmdlet.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Path 'C:/src/t/sv' |
    ForEach-Object {
        Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName `
            -Destination "C:/src/t/sv2/$($_.BaseName -replace ' ','_')_$(Get-Date -format 'ddMMyy')$($_.Extension)" -WhatIf
    }
```